# Tangent lines to curve parallel to $x-4y = 2$

Tags: calculus

How do I find the tangent lines to $y = (x-2)/(x+2)$ that are parallel to $x-4y =2$? The problem also asks me to specify first the line with the smaller $y$-intercept. I tried the quotient rule but I wasn't able to get a correct answer. Please list the steps in any of your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the tangents using Analytic geometry too.

Any line parallel to $x-4y=2$ is of the form $x-4y=c\implies x=4y+c$

Let us find the intersections of the parallel line with then given curve.

So, $$y=\frac{4y+c-2}{4y+c+2}\implies 4y^2+y(c-2)+2-c=0$$

As this is a quadratic equation in $y$

for tangency, the discriminant $(c-2)^2-4\cdot4(2-c)$ must be $0$

$\implies (c-2)(c+14)=0$

So, the equation of the tangents are $x=4y+2$ and $x=4y-14$ with $y$ intercepts $2,-14$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
If lines are parallel, they share the same slope.

Write $x-4y=2$ in the form $y=ax+b$, and then $a$ is your slope.

Then, the derivative of a function is the slope of its tangent line. Hence, compute the derivative of $\frac{x-2}{x+2}$, and find where it is equal to $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \frac{x-2}{x+2}$. Note that $f'(x) = \frac{4}{(x+2)^2}$.

The other line can be written as $y=g(x) = \frac{x-2}{4}$, which has slope $g'(x) = \frac{1}{4}$ (for all $x$).

So you want to solve $f'(x) = \frac{1}{4}$. If you expand this you will get a simple quadratic equation in $x$, which has two solutions (below).

> $x=-6$, $x=2$.

The tangent lines have the same slope as the line (ie, $\frac{1}{4}$), but pass through the point on the curve $(x,f(x))$. The points on the curve are given by

> $(-6,2)$ and $(2,0)$.

The equation of the tangent lines will be of the form $y = \frac{1}{4}x
 +c$, where you have to figure out the two values of $c$ that will result in a line passing through the above points (see below).

> $y=\frac{1}{4}x + \frac{7}{2}$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}x - \frac{1}{2}$.